# Google Colab: pip install and imports from a custom script

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

In MyDrive/colab a I have these files:

00-imports.py with content...

```
!pip install boto3
```

classes.py with content...

```py
class Test

  def __init__(self):
    print('test objecjt created')

  def test1(self):
    print('test::test1')
```

Now, my notebook looks like this...

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)


import sys 
sys.path.insert(0, '/content/drive/MyDrive/colab')

from classes import Test

t = Test()

print(t.test1)

import boto3
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '****'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '****'

s3 = boto3.client("s3", aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
```

If I run it....

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a227f9818978> in <module>()
      3 AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'YgevaTvOHLs/fqfkoZ/MpX+kOMQa14sqhyCfcTTz'
      4 
----> 5 s3 = boto3.client("s3", aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

NameError: name 'boto3' is not defined
```

It's any way to call pip from my drive scripts?
It's any way to do the imports in those scripts?

The idea is create some libs in order to clean colab notebooks. Revome instalations, imports and clients from main notebook page and hidde all this stuff in my drive scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way:

```py
import os

requisite='boto3'
os.system(f"pip install {requisite}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't install boto3 like that in a .py file
If you strictly want to use a python file, you can install it like that:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['pip', 'install', "boto3"])
```

or you could make an `install.sh` script containing your installs
and you can execute that script using `!sh install.sh` or `!bash install.sh`

Comment: @mor, what solution is better? yours or mine? any diference at all? Thanks.

Comment: @icalvete Python docu says: "subprocess module intends to replace several older modules and functions like ```os.system``` "
But honestly I think they're pretty much equal